# generate pdf if object is persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, wicked-pdf

I'm using [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gem to generate a pdf file:

I want to generate the pdf only if the object is **persisted/saved** in database:

Something like this:

```
def new
  @invoice = Invoice.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
  end
end

def create
  @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @invoice.save
      format.html { redirect_to invoice_path(@invoice), notice: "Yesss!") }
    else
      format.html { render action: new, :alert => "Oops :(" }
    end
    format.pdf do
      @example_text = "exampletext"
        render :pdf => "file_name",
               :template => 'path/to/template'
    end
  end
end
```

But with this code only respond to html. I want generate the pdf inside of:

```
if @invoice.save
  #generate the pdf here
  format.html { redirect_to invoice_path(@invoice), notice: "Yesss!") }
else
```

**How can I do it, Can I use a callback?**

Comment: Do you want an embedded PDF file in your HTML document or do you simply want to render a PDF?  If the later is the case you want to change format.save to your pdf block instead of .html and I believe it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `respond_to` block like so:

```
def create
...
  if @invoice.save
   render :pdf=>"file_name",
   :template=>'/path/to/template'
  else
    render action: "new", :alert=>"Oops :("
  end
 end
```

Comment: Thank you, but this fix is not working fine! I get `Completed 406 Not Acceptable`

Comment: @hyperrjas I'm not sure if this will work with you, but I removed the respond to block on my .csv file and it worked.  I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Thank you the last fix is working fine :). The problem was with respond_to block. Thanks!